# Error while reading .xlsx file with openpyxl

Tags: python, list, openpyxl, xlsx

having hard time reading .xlsx file using openpyxl. sorry for being not very explit while stating my original question.
Following is the code:

```
`import openpyxl
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='file_name.xlsx')`
```

Following is the traceback:

```
 `3 from openpyxl import load_workbook
  4 workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook \
----> 5     (filename='file_name.xlsx')

  ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
316                         data_only, keep_links)
--> 317     reader.read()
318     return reader.wb

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in read(self)
277         self.read_theme()
278         apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
--> 279         self.read_worksheets()
280         self.parser.assign_names()
281         if not self.read_only:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in read_worksheets(self)
225                 ws._rels = rels
226                 ws_parser = WorksheetReader(ws, fh, self.shared_strings, self.data_only)
--> 227                 ws_parser.bind_all()
228 
229             # assign any comments to cells

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py     in bind_all(self)
406 
407     def bind_all(self):
--> 408         self.bind_cells()
409         self.bind_merged_cells()
410         self.bind_hyperlinks()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py in bind_cells(self)
331         for idx, row in self.parser.parse():
332             for cell in row:
--> 333                 style =     self.ws.parent._cell_styles[cell['style_id']]
334                 c = Cell(self.ws, row=cell['row'],      column=cell['column'], style_array=style)
  335                 c._value = cell['value']

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
```

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more information like the code you are running that gives you this error and any type of data you are passing to it.

Comment: ***"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"***: What did you not understand from the error message? [Edit] your question and explain in detail.

Comment: thanks all. Just updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @questad: Have you proven you can open `filename='file_name.xlsx'` with Excel? [Edit] your question and show the `openpyxl.__version__`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that `cell['style_id']` is going to return a string and `_cell_styles[]` is expecting an integer to index with.

Have you tried looking at what is in `cell['style_id']`, and if needed, converting to an integer?